# Windows Live Messenger API in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, http, api, windows-live-messenger

If I want to make a Cocoa application that communicates with Windows Live Messenger, is there an API to do that, so I can make something like, for example, the eBuddy app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [LibPurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple).

Also look at [Adium](http://adium.im/), which is a Cocoa app that uses LibPurple, and is open source.